# Google maps API not loading all markers - except on multiple reloads

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm using Google's maps API with the geocoder API. But when the map initially loads it's not showing all the larkers. However, if I refresh/reload the paid several times, eventually all the markers load. I am aware that the rate limit is 2500 per day or 50 per second. My list of locations is only about 80 so shouldn't affect the daily limit, but could it be exceeding the 'per second' limit?

When the map isn't showing all the markers I get "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.results[0].geometry')" in the console. Then after a few refreshes and all the markers are loaded I no longer get that error.

Is it possible to echo out any rate limit alerts from google?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
       var map;
       var elevator;
       var myOptions = {
           zoom: 6,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.027410, -1.801189),
       };
       map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

       var addresses = [<?php
            foreach ($addresses as $loc) {
              echo "'".$loc."', ";
            }
       ?>];
       var markers=[];
       var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
       for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
           $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false&components=country:gb', null, function (data) {
               var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
               var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: latlng,
                   map: map
               });
               markers.push(marker);
               markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
           });
       }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: How many addresses do you have? Are you sure you stay within allowed QPS for Geocoding API? Also, I cannot see any API key in your geocoding requests, that means you share the quota with somebody else.

Comment: We have about 100 addresses, which is well within the daily limit, but as I said in my question I suspect the issue may be the 50 per second limit. Is there a way to batch the requests into 50 at a time but add them to the same map? Or maybe set timeout and slow down the requests? p.s. the api key is in the api call in a separate script url, I just didn't include it in the question as I didn't think it was part of the problem.

Comment: Note that you are sending web service requests directly from your JavaScript code via `$.getJSON`, the API key you introduced in script tag doesn't matter, because it's valid for Maps JavaScript API only, for web service you should add a `key` parameter in URL string. And indeed you should control the QPS to stay within 50. It's up to you to implement this throttling.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice @xomena I'll give it a go.